# Make a telephone call and send different DTMF tones during the call in iOS

Tags: ios, ivr, dtmf

Is it possible to call a phone number programmatically in iOS and send different DTMF tones during the call?.
Basically I want an App to handle the IVR call. I don't know anything about iOS programming. I just want to know the feasibility so that I will put further effort.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this interactively within the bounds of the iOS SDK (ie, in an App Store app).

You can, however, build [a `tel` URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2806). See [the Apple documentation on phone links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) for more details if you think this will work for your needs.